# Looping Through Setting Inner HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can only use JavaScript to resolve the issue. I tried writing a for loop, but am getting undefined when hovering. I basically have a dynamically generated submenu. When a li is hovered over on the submenu, the inner HTML is suppose to change for the content area to the right of the lis.

```
sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0].children[2].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0].children[1].innerHTML;
});
sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0].children[2].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[1].children[1].innerHTML;
});
sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[2].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0].children[2].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[2].children[1].innerHTML;
});
sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[3].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0].children[2].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[3].children[1].innerHTML;
});
sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[4].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0].children[2].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[4].children[1].innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: What's in `sideCol`? And you could use `document.querySelectorAll` to ease your pain.

Comment: The problem was that the code was not DRY and sideCol is a created div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The looping is very simple, just use local variable (ix).

```
var count = sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++) {
    (function(ix) {
        sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[ix]
            .addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[0]
                    .children[2].innerHTML = 
                document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content')[ix]
                    .children[1].innerHTML;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: My only follow up question to this would be what if the number of elements fluctuates? So if i<5 should become i<10 etc. Is there a way to run the looping based on the number of lis?

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach()` to loop over the elements and bind the event listeners. This will then give you the index as a closure variable, which you can use in the handler function to access the appropriate element.

```
[].forEach.call(sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li'), function(el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        var explorers = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryExplorer-content');
        explorers[0].children[2].innerHTML = explorers[i].children[1].innerHTML;
    });
});
```

Comment: This returned an error that said forEach is not a function

Comment: Sorry, forgot that it doesn't work directly on `NodeList`, you have to convert it to an array or use the `.call` method in the edited answer.